# Testing irreducibility of integer polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am currently maintaining a Julia software package `CommutativeRings` which implements also factorization of integer polynomials according to Bareiss and Zassenhaus. If the polynomial is of the form $f(x^{a})$ where $a > 1$ it checks first, if $f(x^{d})$ is reducible for some divisor $d | a$ to exploit this information. The question arose, if it is necessary to check *all* divisors, or if it would be sufficient to consider for example prime factors of $a$.

If p and q are two different prime numbers, and $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $\mathrm{Z}[x]$. Is it true or is there a counter-example for the following statement:

If $f(x^p)$ is irreducible and $f(x^q)$ is irreducible, then $f(x^{p q})$ is irreducible.

Or more general for $f(x^{p q r})$  for any integer $r$.

I tried a long list of generated irreducible polynomials $f$ of degrees up to $10$, and $a = 6$ without finding a counter-example.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I think it is true that if $\gcd(r,s)=1$, $f(x^r)$ and $f(x^s)$ are irreducible, then $f(x^{rs})$ is also irreducible. If $\deg f=n$, and $\alpha\in\Bbb{C}$ is a zero of $f$, then $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha):\Bbb{Q}]=n$, $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha^{1/r}):\Bbb{Q}]=rn$ and $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha^{1/s}):\Bbb{Q}]=sn$. As the least common multiple of $rn$ and $sn$ is $rsn$, it follows that $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha^{1/rs}):\Bbb{Q}]=rsn$ and we are done, right?